# Access to names of all files of directory via FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I would like to know, if there is a native way, (like a variable of the FileSystemWatcher class), to get a list of all the files presents in the directory watched by the FileSystemWatcher once started. The watcher can raise events when a file is modified, deleted,..., but is it able to get the name of all the files of the directory it is watching once it begins his surveillance, without necessarily having a specified event.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/filesystemwatcher try to capture it using some of the inherit events perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this solution. I was wondering if there was a way to get the same result with the FileSystemWatcher that I initialized to monitor a folder of files.

Comment: Why would such a thing exist? `FileSystemWatcher` is about watching for changes, not basic filesystem operations.